# Variables that best discriminate groups based on the glmnet package

Tags: r, glmnet, lasso-regression

I ultimately want to find a set of proteins that best discriminates three groups (low, med, high) using the elastic-net regression method.

There's the example code reproducible:

```
tempcv <- cv.glmnet(x=as.matrix(iris[,-5]), y=iris[,5], family="multinomial", 
                    nfolds=20, alpha=0.5)
coefsMin <- coef(tempcv, s="lambda.min")
```

Then what I get is the following:

```
$setosa
5 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                     1
(Intercept)  15.119192
Sepal.Length -1.897589
Sepal.Width   5.455627
Petal.Length -2.807969
Petal.Width  -5.942061

$versicolor
5 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                     1
(Intercept)   4.795799
Sepal.Length  1.726752
Sepal.Width   .       
Petal.Length -1.160588
Petal.Width  -1.978123

$virginica
5 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                      1
(Intercept)  -19.914991
Sepal.Length   .       
Sepal.Width   -3.925362
Petal.Length   4.536932
Petal.Width    9.236506
```

In this case, using the absolute value of each coefficient, can I interpret this result as follows? 
***The two variables that best discriminate "setosa" from other two groups ("versicolor" and "virginica") are Sepal.Width (5.46) and Petal.Width (-5.94).***

If this is wrong, then how can I select some variables/features that best discriminate groups?

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For glmnet, the coefficients you get are in the same scale as your input, from the [vignette](https://glmnet.stanford.edu/articles/glmnet.html):

> Note that for family = "gaussian", glmnet standardizes  to have unit
> variance before computing its lambda sequence (and then unstandardizes
> the resulting coefficients).

In your example, the independent variables are not scaled. Therefore, the magnitude of your coefficients will depend on the scale of the independent variable. For example, the coefficient of  `Sepal.Width` means for each unit of `Sepal.Width` it increases the log odds by 5.46. But you can see their value range are very different:

```
apply(iris[,1:4],2,range)
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
[1,]          4.3         2.0          1.0         0.1
[2,]          7.9         4.4          6.9         2.5
```

Your assumption holds only when you scale your independent variables before applying the lasso.

One option is to use [vip](https://koalaverse.github.io/vip/articles/vip.html) to infer the variable importance, you can see [this](https://bradleyboehmke.github.io/HOML/regularized-regression.html#lm-features) for more examples.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate it, @StupidWolf ! Taking the iris data was only for the example. The variables in the original data that I were using was manually normalized (mean 0 and var 1).